# jQuery.timeago.js cdn fallback to local js

Tags: jquery, html

As title says, anyone has any idea how to do it? currently i am using

```
http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-timeago/0.11.4/jquery.timeago.js
```

but i am looking for a solution to fallback to local js but i don know how to.

**extra**

there are already solution for jquery

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>-->
<script>!window.jQuery && document.write(unescape('%3Cscript src="javascripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"%3E%3C/script%3E'))</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-timeago/0.11.4/jquery.timeago.js"></script>
<script>!$.fn.timeago && document.write(unescape('%3Cscript src="javascripts/jquery.timeago.js"%3E%3C/script%3E'))</script>
```

The strategy is actually the same, the way to check for jQuery module is using `$.fn.pluginName`.